# Map MediumBlob between mySQL & hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, blob

I am trying to map mediumblob in MYSQL with `type='mediumblob'` in Hibernate property file but I am getting the below exception.

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: BLOB,
>   for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(INDEX_ZIP)]

This is the property I am setting.

```
<property name="indexZipBlob" type="BLOB">
    <column name="INDEX_ZIP" /> 
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<property name="indexZipBlob" not-null="true">
  <column name="INDEX_ZIP" sql-type="MEDIUMBLOB" />
</property>
```